# Pick the Packages from Heaviest to Lightest

Tags: c#, package

so I have a test assessment that I need to do their is one question that I have been having trouble. I need to pick the heaviest object(the biggest number) and place them in stacking order (heavy on bottom, light on top) the problem that I'm having is that I don't know where to **start** exactly, the code that I'm using is C#, However I do know that I have to use the sorting method. so my main issue is that I'm trying to find out what my beginning move is and how to progress from their. Also I believe this may be on codin games but have not yet to find it anywhere, if anyone can find the name of it that would also be of great help.

[image: The question]
[image: the default code]
[image: visual]

Answer (score 3):

Without any allocation, collections and lists:

```
using System;       

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = 13;
        var b = 14;
        var c = 15;
        
        Console.WriteLine(Solve(a, b, c));      
    }
    
    public static int Solve(int weight0, int weight1, int weight2)
    {
        return weight0 > weight1
            ? weight0 > weight2
                ? 0 : 2
            : weight1 > weight2
                ? 1 : 2;
    }   
}
```

Mind that it does not check for negatives.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in this case, calling `Sort` is an overkill, as it is used on `IEnumerable`s, which you dont have and need to create.

I think that it would be easier to just use this page to learn from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Chash-program-to-find-the-maximum-of-three-numbers

It looks like sorting would not help in that case as you need to return the index of the weight, not the size.

You could try to create a dictionary with index and weight and use linq to find the biggest weight:

```
    public static int GetHeaviestWeightIndex(int weight1, int weight2, int weight3)
    {
        var weightToIndexMapping = new Dictionary<int, int> {{weight1, 0}, {weight2, 1}, {weight3, 2}};
        return weightToIndexMapping[weightToIndexMapping.Keys.Max()];
    }
```

If you insist on using `Sort` you can try and use a `SortedDictoinary` like here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorteddictionary-class-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 0):

I Solve the same in PHP

```
Pick the packages from the heaviest to the lightest one.
function solve($weight0, $weight1, $weight2) {
  // Write your code here
  // To debug (equivalent to var_dump): error_log(var_export($var, true));
  if(($weight0 >= $weight1) && ($weight0 >= $weight2)){
    return 0;
  }else if(($weight1 >= $weight0) && ($weight1 >= $weight2)){
    return 1;
  }else{
    return 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't especially useful since the question was tagged with C#. If you want, you can post a new question asking for something similar in PHP, and then answer your own question with this code. (Assuming there aren't any other threads related to this for PHP already.)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need code for python for heavier to lighter packages then its below:

def solve(weight_0, weight_1, weight_2):

#write your code here

#code below is for excercise 1 and 3 (7 different boxes and 6 boxes with an equality)

```
if(weight_2 > weight_0):
   return 2

elif(weight_1 < weight_2):
   return 0

elif(weight_1 > weight_2):
   return 1

else:
   print("")
```

#code below is for exercise 2 (indentical boxes)

```
if (weight_0 < weight_1):
    return 0 

 elif(weight_1 < weight_2):
     return 1

 elif(weight_1 == weight_2):
    return 2
```

Comment: Although you are very helpful, this site is not meant for sharing answers of courses. Other platforms are much more effective for that.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I wrote for this was in `Kotlin` like this :

```
import java.util.*
import java.io.*
import java.math.*

fun solve(weight0: Int, weight1: Int, weight2: Int): Int {
    var array = arrayOf<Int>()
    array += weight0
    array += weight1
    array += weight2

    val max = array.max()
    var index = array.indexOf(max)

    return index
}
```

Comment: This question is about C#, not Java, so this doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: He just said that he is using C# in codingame you can change the language if you want too, and i sait it that my best answer was in kotlin